# Push Notifications with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have the following database structure in Firebase Database

[image: Database]

and I want to implement a cloud function that triggers a push notification every time a new node is created. This Push Notification should only be received by the person belonging to the UID where new content is created.

So far I got this :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNewBestellung = functions.database.ref('/userBestellungen/{UID}').onWrite(event=>{

  const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'New Order!',
        body: 'New Order from (//Here I want to insert the content of the node Tischnummer)!',
        badge: '1',
        sound: 'default',
    }

  };

})
```

The path is `/userBestellungen/(UID)/(orderID)/(some content)` and I want to send the push message only to the UID belonging to the new created content.

I am new to swift programming so doing some java cloud functions I have no ideas of is not easy for me I hope you can help me

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging doesn't send to Firebase Auth UIDs.  It sends to either topics or direct to devices using a device ID token.  You're going to have to come up with a way to record the possible device IDs for a given user, and associate them in a database.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42102062, https://stackoverflow.com/q/43401235,